# IntelliJ can not find file in same project folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I put a file in my projects folder in intellij but it complains keep gettting file not found. I tried putting it in the src folder but get same results. How do I get my code to locate the file? The name of the file is "movies.txt". Thank you.

[image]

Comment: you can check the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your application the root folder is what it is defined in the Working directory in the Run/Debug Configuration view:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

By default it run in the project root and your file would then be ./src/movies.txt

Comment: `movies.txt` is in the project root, not under `src`.